# How to fix "No default VPC for this user, status code: 400" in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to fix this piece of code and I would like to create bastion host but I am receiving:
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error occurred:
* aws_instance.bastion: 1 error occurred:
* aws_instance.bastion: Error launching source instance: VPCIdNotSpecified: No default VPC for this user
status code: 400, request id: daf3dd12-d7c4-469a-9be5-3707c0490c2a

I am using Terraform 0.11

Code:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
    cidr_block       = "${var.main_vpc_cidr}"
    instance_tenancy = "default"
    enable_dns_support = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true

     tags {
         Name = "main"
            }
        }


 resource "aws_subnet" "subnet1" {
   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
   cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
   availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"


  tags {
    Name = "app-subnet-1"
    }
 }



    ########## Create bastion host ######

##resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {

  ami                         = "ami-0fdc6293d3e87a86e"
  key_name                    = "${aws_key_pair.bastion_key.key_name}"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
  security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.bastion-sg.name}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  
}

resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {
  name   = "bastion-security-group"
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0 
    to_port     = 0 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "bastion_key" {
  key_name   = "your_key_name"
  public_key = "ssh-rsa AAA

output "bastion_public_ip" {
  value = "${aws_instance.bastion.public_ip}"
}
```

variables.tf file:

```
variable "aws_access_key" {}
variable "aws_secret_key" {}

variable "aws_region" {
    description = "EC2 Region for the VPC"
    default = "eu-west-1"
}
variable "availability_zone1" {
    description = "Avaialbility Zones"
    default = "eu-west-1a"
}

variable "availability_zone2" {
    description = "Avaialbility Zones"
    default = "eu-west-1b"
}
variable "main_vpc_cidr" {
    description = "CIDR of the VPC"
    default = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to get a default VPC running, and have the option of using the AWS CLI, this worked for me:

```
aws ec2 create-default-vpc
```

Reference: [AWS Docs - Default VPC and default subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html#create-default-vpc)

Answer (score 4):

There are **several mistakes** in the code, e.g.:

- Creation of a custom vpc without any subnets, route tables, internet gateway (or maybe you want to use a default VPC only which does not exist?),
- `tags` in the main vpc should be `tags =` ,
- `security_groups` in the bastion should be `vpc_security_group_ids` when using custom vpc,
- `aws_key_pair` is malformed.

If you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve, a more detailed answer could be provided.

#### Code updated

The code deploys in `us-east-1`. You may need to modify it back to your region (e.g. ami, availability zones).

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
    cidr_block       = "${var.main_vpc_cidr}"
    instance_tenancy = "default"
    enable_dns_support = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true

     tags = {
         Name = "main"
            }
        }


 resource "aws_subnet" "subnet1" {
   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
   cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"
   availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"


  tags  =  {
    Name = "app-subnet-1"
    }
 }
 resource "aws_subnet" "subnet2" {
   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
   cidr_block = "10.0.2.0/24"
   availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone2}"


     tags  =  {
      Name = "app-subnet-2"
     }
   }
  resource "aws_subnet" "subnet3" {
   vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.3.0/24"
    availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"


   tags  =  {
     Name = "elb-subnet-1"
 }
}
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet4" {
 vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
 cidr_block = "10.0.4.0/24"
 availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone2}"


 tags  =  {
  Name = "elb-subnet-2"
  }
 }
    resource "aws_subnet" "subnet5-database" {
    vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
    cidr_block = "10.0.5.0/24"
     availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone1}"


  tags  =  {
    Name = "db-subnet-1"
 }
}
 resource "aws_subnet" "subnet6-database" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.6.0/24"
  availability_zone = "${var.availability_zone2}"


  tags  =  {
  Name = "db-subnet-2"
  }
 }

 resource "aws_internet_gateway" "main-igw" {
   vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  tags = {
   Name = "main-igw"
   }
   }


resource "aws_eip" "nat" {
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main-natgw" {
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.nat.id}"
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.subnet4.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "main-nat"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "main-public-rt" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.main-igw.id}"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "main-public-rt"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "main-private-rt" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = "${aws_nat_gateway.main-natgw.id}"
  }

  tags  = {
    Name = "main-private-rt"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-assoc-1" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet3.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-public-rt.id}"
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "public-assoc-2" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet4.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-public-rt.id}"
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-assoc-1" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet1.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-private-rt.id}"
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-assoc-2" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet2.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-private-rt.id}"
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-assoc-3" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet5-database.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-private-rt.id}"
}
resource "aws_route_table_association" "private-assoc-4" {
  subnet_id      = "${aws_subnet.subnet6-database.id}"
  route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.main-private-rt.id}"
}


    ########## Create bastion host ######

##resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {

  ami                         = "ami-0fdc6293d3e87a86e"
  key_name                    = "${aws_key_pair.bastion_key.key_name}"
  instance_type               = "t2.micro"
 # security_groups             = ["${aws_security_group.bastion-sg.name}"]
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["${aws_security_group.bastion-sg.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnet1.id
  
}

resource "aws_security_group" "bastion-sg" {
  name   = "bastion-security-group"
##  vpc_id = "${aws_default_vpc.default.id}"
   vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"

  ingress {
    protocol    = "tcp"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = -1
    from_port   = 0 
    to_port     = 0 
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "bastion_key" {
   key_name   = "your_key_name"
   public_key = "ssh-rsa AAA
}

output "bastion_public_ip" {
  value = "${aws_instance.bastion.public_ip}"
}
```

Comment: But I have a code and variables.tf file I have added to this post. Please look at this additional file.

Comment: @TJstock I just removed duplicate variables.

Comment: So I run terraform again but I have the different error now and I am not sure about what is the problem:
Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
        status code: 400, request id: 0c2fc9c5-9d41-41fe-8a22-c827d9214706

Can be a problem with public_key because I am using a testing not existing key in this script? What do you think. My EC2 instance doesn't exist on AWS console but the rest of configuration is. I have all Subtnes, VPC etc.

Comment: @TJstock Check your AMI and other staff. I used `us-east-1`. AMI are region specific. For your region, AMI can be different. If you want, you can make new question with the new error messages and relevant info.

Comment: @TJstock Yes, public key also requires checking.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a default VPC running worked for me.

[Default VPC and default subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/default-vpc.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a default VPC, then the error will go away.

Basically, **you don't have a default VPC**, that is why you got the error.